# How to launch a Python Spyder session through script / shortcut?

Tags: python-2.7, ipython, spyder

I have this code to launch a Spyder IDE, in Anaconda 2, Python 2.7 :

```
from spyderlib import start_app
main1= start_app.main()
main1.load_session('/project27/_test01_.session.tar')

'''
from spyderlib.utils.iofuncs import load_session
load_session(filename+'.session.tar')
'''
```

Code method to load session is here: https://github.com/jromang/spyderlib/blob/master/spyderlib/spyder.py

```
    #---- Sessions
    def load_session(self, filename=None):
        """Load session"""
        if filename is None:
            self.redirect_internalshell_stdio(False)
            filename, _selfilter = getopenfilename(self, _("Open session"),
                        getcwd(), _("Spyder sessions")+" (*.session.tar)")
            self.redirect_internalshell_stdio(True)
            if not filename:
                return
        if self.close():
            self.next_session_name = filename
```

the 1st part comes from Anaconda Scripts where Spyder script.
It seems not working to load session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spyder sessions were removed in Spyder 3.0. Now the same functionality is provided by Projects (which also save the list of open files in the Editor), so please update to that version.

Besides, Spyder 3.1 will come with a new option called `--project` to load a project at startup (Spyder 3.1 will be released on January 17/2017).

Answer (score -1):

For people still using only Spyder 2.0 (....), there is a small hack possible to create shortcut of session (SPyder session launched directly with shortcut).
Here, the code :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys, time, os
file_session= ''
if len(sys.argv) > 1 : 
  file_session= sys.argv[1]
  print file_session

sys.argv= sys.argv[:1]


from spyderlib import start_app
if file_session != '' :
  main1= start_app.main( file_session)
else :
  main1= start_app.main()
```